# jQuery.val() integer datatype comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am bit confused of this integer comparison using jQuery

I have 2 input values.

- input type="number" class="highestBid" value=

  input type="number" min="0" class=" bid" name="bid" id="bid"

so basically the inputed bid from user in the 2nd input field must be always higher than the current highest bid.

I used following jQuery code to compare between these 2 codes :

```
$(function(){
 $('.bid').focusout(function(){
  if($('.bid').val() <= $('.highestBid').val()){
    $('.bidPlaced').prop('disabled', true);
  }
  else{
    $('.bidPlaced').prop('disabled', false);
    $('.buyItNow').prop('disabled', false)
  }
  });
```

});

The code works fine, but just now there is a bug I figured out

if the current highest bid is : $123
and the user input : $21
the function will not work

but if the user key in $122, the code will work

I found out that the jQuery code just compare the first value which in this case is $(1)23 to $(2)1.

can anybody tell me what is wrong with the jQuery code?

Thanks!

Comment: use $(this).val() instead of $('.bid').val()

Comment: nothing changes sir. the result still the same. it just compare the first number

Comment: it seems .val() is returning strings...so use parseInt or parseFloat  before comparing

Answer (score 15):

When you get a value our of an `input` element using jQuery `.val()`, it will always be a `string`. It doesn't matter that the `input` element is `type="number"`. The *javascript* value is a `string`.

If you know your numbers will always be integers, you can `parseInt`:

```
if (parseInt($('.bid').val()) <= parseInt($('.highestBid').val())) {
```

If your numbers possibly have decimal places, you can also use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`.

```
if (parseFloat($('.bid').val()) <= parseFloat($('.highestBid').val())) {
```

BTW, it is not jQuery that is behaving this way, it is the javascript language. All jQuery does is use javascript to read out the value of the input element in a convenient way, and give it back to you as a string.

It's up to you to know that these values are always `string`s, and if you need to compare them as `number`s, use javascript functions like `parseInt` and `parseFloat` to convert them into the correct javascript types before comparing.